# Perl fails to set locale on AIX 7.1

Tags: perl, aix, locale

After setting user language to Chinese with GB18030 encoding in SMIT, the
following env variable were added to the user's `.profile`:

```
LANG=Zh_CN
LC_MESSAGE=%l.%c
NLSPATH=/usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N:/usr/lib/nls/msg/%l.%c/%N:/usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat.....
```

But when I run perl, it give me this warning:

```
perl: warning: setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
     LC_ALL = (unset),
     LC_FASTMSG = "true"
     LC_MESSAGE = "%l.%c"
     LANG = "Zh_CN"
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Is that the entire error message? "Please check that your locale settings" _what_? Could it need you to also set LC_ALL?

Comment: @terdon Perl's message goes on for an extra two lines after that (“are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").”) but the question contains all the relevant information. Setting `LC_ALL` is most definitely not necessary.

Comment: Is `%l.%c` a valid locale setting on AIX? I'm not familiar with that syntax, but I'm no AIX expert. Could you point to the documentation about this feature?

Answer (score 1):

One [piece of documentation I could find](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.nls/doc/nlsgdrf/locale_env.htm) says only:

```
LC_MESSAGES

    Specifies the locale to use for LC_MESSAGES category information. The
    LC_MESSAGES category determines rules governing affirmative and
    negative responses and the locale (language) for messages and menus.
```

I could not find any documentation that mentions that "%l.%c" (presumably for "locale" and "charset"?) are acceptable. It may be a good idea to try setting both LANG and LC_MESSAGES to `zh_CN` instead of their current values (note the case).

```
 LC_FASTMSG = "true"
 LC_MESSAGE = "%l.%c"
```

Those both appear undocumented; according to the documentation I linked to above the proper names are `LC__FASTMSG` (two underscores) and `LC_MESSAGES` (plural).